# What is a 'disallowed entry' when nmap scans through the Robots.txt file?

Tags: robots.txt, nmap

I have been using nmap to scan an IP address, and one part of the output is:

| http-robots.txt: 1 disallowed entry

What does this mean?

| http-robots.txt: 1 disallowed entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an entry in the robots.txt file of the form `Disallow: X`. This means that at least some User-Agent has been instructed not to request these URIs. A list of them should be listed below the line you showed. You can read more about the robots.txt standard and format on [robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).